# Only invoke method if condition is 30 or over

Tags: c#

When condition `v` is higher than 30 it keep sending SMS in app.
However, I want it to only send 1 SMS, then resend SMS when `v` goes back to 29, then 30.

```
if(v >= 30) 
{
    do 
    {
        var SmsMessenger = (CrossMessaging.Current.SmsMessenger);

        if(SmsMessenger.CanSendSmsInBackground)
        {
            SmsMessenger.SendSmsInBackground("+000000", "Test")
        }
    } 
    while(((currentLocation.Speed * 3600) / 1000) != 20);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a flag, to call the message once.

```
bool IsSmsSended = false;


if(v >= 30 && !IsSmsSended) {
   do {
      var SmsMessenger= (CrossMessaging.Current.SmsMessenger);
      if(SmsMessenger.CanSendSmsInBackground){
         SmsMessenger.SendSmsInBackground("+000000","Test")
      }
   }
   while(((currentLocation.Speed * 3600) /1000) !=20);
   IsSmsSended = true;
}else if(v < 30){
   IsSmsSended = false;
}
```

You have to reset IsSmsSended, if the value is under 30. Look at the else if.

P.S.: Make IsSmsSended global.